# How to call a javascript function in vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I need to assign the result of a javascript function to a variable in vbscript

```
<script language="javascript">
    function answer_process() {
    var aux = document.getElementById('complete');
    return aux.value;
    }
</script>

<%
    ....
    Dim despesa_aux 
    despesa_aux = answer_processo()
    ....
%>
```

I need to know the best way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you mean classic ASP, you cannot. ASP runs on the server, generates some output, sends the output through the internet to another computer possibly in another continent and finally that computer executes JavaScript. It cannot send back stuff to the server to be processed by an entirely different language that already finished executing.

Comment: So what is the best option of resolving this?
The user is suppose to choose one answer in a dropdown (yes or no). and the function answer_process() can retrieve that information

Comment: Submit the form the dropdown belongs to?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and help Álvaro González

Answer (score 0):

```
despesa_aux = call answer_processo()
```